# How to know what variables can be accessed in Mirth?

Tags: mirth

How to know what variables can be accessed for any given screen in Mirth (v3.10)?

Eg. When setting up a Channel Source for a Database Reader connector type, I realized that I can access the variables of the fields that are being read by the SQL query when writing the Post-Process SQL query purely by experimentation (else there was nothing on the screen that would indicate that I could have done that). I see a blank box to the right of the Post-Process SQL query box, but it's empty so IDK what that's for (unlike the variables that I can drag from the right of the File Writer channel destination connection).
[image]
Looking at the "Velocity Variable Replacement" and "Variable Maps" sections of the Mirth [user's manual](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-310-user-guide.pdf) did not have much detail on this question either.

Anyone with more experience know where I could see this information (is it a link, something in the UI itself, docs somewhere)?